# When I try to ask a question, the submit button freezes

Tags: bug, android-app, asking-questions

I was trying to ask a question about photo-electric effect on the Physics.SE (one of the choices mentioned in the list of sites). I tried multiple times, but the submit button didn't work. The preview button is functional.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Xiaomi
- Device Model: Redmi 3S
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (V8.5.4.0.MALMIED)

Comment: On what site? When it freeze? Sure you don't see any error message? You gave zero details, it's impossible to help without more details.

Comment: I was trying to ask a question about photo-electric effect on the physics site (one of the choices mentioned in the list of sites). I tried multiple times, but the submit button didn't work. The preview button is functional.

Comment: I am new to this app. There may be something I am doing wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Well you don't have account on that site yet. Try to join it with a browser, then hopefully you'll be able to ask questions via the app there. The app is dead by now, its development frozen, so I wouldn't waste much time with it. Just use a browser and all works just fine. (There are good browser apps for mobile devices, and SE sites got special mobile view)

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard  Thanks.

Comment: I have the same experience, on my computer, on chrome, different versions..